# Why does my resize function does not call the css top attribute to change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
window.onload = function() {
    //set position of background overlay in section4
    $('.overlay-wrap4').css('top', $('#section4').offset().top + "px");
    $('.overlay-wrap4').css('height', $('#section4').height() + "px");
}
window.onresize = function() {
    console.log("well called")
    $('.overlay-wrap4').css('top', $('#section4').offset().top + "px"); //where I put a comment
    $('.overlay-wrap4').css('height', $('#section4').height() + "px");
}
```

When the document is all loaded, it successfully executes the 2 lines above, but when the windows is resized, it does not executes the instruction where I put a comment. But if I copy paste it into the console, it does well the action
So why is it not executed inside the onresize function when I resize the window ?
The console log well called is well executed

Comment: Yes, when I resize the window, the section4 offset top is well updated in my console log

Comment: I did it and it does not solve my problem

Comment: you can see the example here https://web2fr-pajot.dunegestion.com/ and execute the scripts here in the console

Comment: No, look well, overlay4 is displayed but not ad the right place when I resize

Comment: Yes, I confirm my question was wrong, you just know now my question

Comment: Please rewrite the question, use jQuery for the load and resize and provide a [mcve]